# Make url for header in web page?

Tags: url, redirect, html, heading

If I'm viewing a long web page and it contains so many sub headers, then the middle of the web page a particular header(Portion) is important. So I wish to open the header in next time,should redirect the control to the header only not beginning of the web page. Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

Near that particular header add:

```
<a name="important"></a>
```

Now you can refer this specific tag on the page like so:

```
http://www.example.com/long-long-page.html#important
```